# How can I check if my server enables IP spoofing through Source Routing

Tags: ip, spoofing

I have seen several articles and forum answers like [IP address spoofing using Source Routing](https://superuser.com/questions/130355/ip-address-spoofing-using-source-routing).
All these articles/answers claim that the most of servers already defend me against this attack.
But I cannot rely on "generally".
I need to check this exactly.
And if my server enables this I should know how to fix my server so that it doesn't.
So, I need the following information:

1) How to organize request with IP spoofed through Source Routing so that I could see response somewhere.

2) How to block such type of request.

Comment: Source routing is blocked in a router not a server.

Comment: @DavidPostill OK. Let it be router. How can I check if my router enables IP spoofing?

Comment: Depends on what make/model router you have. It will be a router firewall setting.

Comment: @DavidPostill OK, the main question still remaining: how can I check if my router enables IP spoofing?

Comment: "Depends on what make/model router you have. It will be a router firewall setting." I don't know the answer for every possible router model.

Comment: "Depends on what make/model router you have." is answer to which part of question - 1) How to organize request with IP spoofed  or 2) How to block such type of request. ?

Comment: Answer to Part 2

Comment: I don't know the answer to Part 1

Comment: OK, thanks! Now I understand. I still hope someone to answer part 1.